# Oracle SQL count days in week for every month

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, sum

I have these two tables (times and sales):

**times**

```
TIME_ID   |   DAY_NAME  |  DAY_NUMBER_IN_WEEK    |  CALENDAR_MONTH_NAME |  CALENDAR_MONTH_ID
1998-01-10|   Monday    |  1                     |  January             |  1684
1998-01-10|   Tuesday   |  2                     |  January             |  1684
1998-01-10|   Wednesday |  3                     |  January             |  1684
...
1998-01-11|   Monday    |  1                     |  February            |  1685
1998-01-11|   Tuesday   |  2                     |  January             |  1685
1998-01-11|   Wednesday |  3                     |  January             |  1685
```

**sales**

```
PROD_ID   |  TIME_ID     |  AMOUNT_SOLD
13        |  1998-01-10  |  1232          
13        |  1998-01-11  |  1233 
14        |  1998-01-11  |  1233
```

I need to make columns for every day in week (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...) and SUM of AMOUNT_SOLD for each PROD_ID for each day for each month.

```
SELECT SUM(times.day_number_in_week), times.calendar_month_name, times.day_name, times.calendar_year
FROM sales
INNER JOIN times  ON times.time_id = sales.time_id
GROUP BY times.calendar_month_number, times.calendar_month_name, times.day_name, times.calendar_year
```

Output:

```
5988    March   Wednesday   1998
9408    April   Thursday    1998
7532    June    Sunday  1998
9220    July    Thursday    1998
7490    July    Sunday  1998
12540   August  Saturday    1998
```

but this sum all Wednesdays for all years, i need sum of amount for 1 month for all days (Wednesday, Monday...) for one month.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    t.calendar_year
    t.calendar_month_name, 
    SUM(case when t.day_number_in_week = 1 then s.amount_sold else 0 end) amount_sold_mon,
    SUM(case when t.day_number_in_week = 2 then s.amount_sold else 0 end) amount_sold_tue,
    SUM(case when t.day_number_in_week = 3 then s.amount_sold else 0 end) amount_sold_wed,
    ...
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN times t ON t.time_id = sales.time_id
GROUP BY t.calendar_year, t.calendar_month_number, t.calendar_month_name
```

Comment: <code>
SELECT 
    times.calendar_year_id,
    times.calendar_month_id, 
    SUM(case when times.day_number_in_week = 1 then sales.amount_sold else 0 end) amount_sold_mon,
    SUM(case when times.day_number_in_week = 2 then sales.amount_sold else 0 end) amount_sold_tue,
    SUM(case when times.day_number_in_week = 3 then sales.amount_sold else 0 end) amount_sold_wed    
FROM sales
INNER JOIN times ON times.time_id = sales.time_id
GROUP BY times.calendar_year_id, times.calendar_month_id, times.day_number_in_week

</code>
Working but i need to calculate it for specific prod_id

Comment: @H.Ivanov: just add a `where` clause that filters on the `prod_id` you want the results for.

Comment: Working perfect, but i need to remove all 0 from SUM function how can i do it? I try with HAVING but dont working... Can you help me, please?